Subject: what is reason? what is the knowledge?

The object of the question of what, is should be human, and the best way to have the right way of thinking is to move away from analyzing the form of human cognition and reinterpret the form of cognition and reconstruct the "way of being" as the "reason for being recognized." The reason for being recognized contains the purpose of the theory established by humans. The cognitive purpose of the object expressed as the way of being depends on the understanding of humans determined by the cognitive methodology that achieves harmony between objects, so there is a risk of viewing humans as the determiner of existence rather than an equal object in nature when looking at philosophy from an objective perspective, which causes arrogance. The situational reasoning result of the decision maker and the object of decision are the same as the relationship between the whole and the components.
Reason should be understood as a concept that has both active and passive meanings located in the gap between the induced or induced object and the recognized or perceived object, and we should not believe that the components shown by the temporal limitations of the object that constitutes the cognitive form that we are proud of being able to fully express the object will necessarily express the entire essence of the object, so I think it is appropriate to exist as a post-formal that points out the problems and limitations that have recently come up.  Humans are located in the gap between the relationship between cognition and the cognized, and it should be understood and recognized as a valuable system to create a system that can see completely passively "the components belonging to the languages within the system of thought that are combined to constitute all theories cognized within the semantic basis by which the system of thought is understood" all the relationships between objects, except for the subject of indirect experience who is the builder and cognizer of the theory, within the time the subject thinks. Therefore, a valuable theory must reflect the times, and it is absolutely necessary to be correctly understood. (I simply reinterpreted the concept of idea as my own theory, using the language of active or passive abstract essence and mode of existence.) Also, the reason for deconstruction should only be implied by empirical results within the limits of overcoming the limits of the system of thought, and should not be the reason itself for wanting to deconstruct it. I think this tends to stay within the horizon of wisdom, and rather leads to a cognitive event of group reason that leads to the mass production of substitutes for reason. Therefore, I think that the system of thought that should be recognized should be viewed as a temporary base system that operates a cognitive system that "differently operates in a methodology that can solve existing problems," and I think that it is a sufficient condition for that temporary base system to become an ideology or theory that creates new human cognition and empirically solves problem situations. Active and passive should be fluid conditions determined according to the underlying system, and they are like the program of the components expressing the situation. Active should be the brain in another sense, that is, the accidental selection, and I will now expand the meaning of selection. Selection in another sense should be thought of as the meaning of subordination as "subordination for nature" or "subordination for the natural existence of an object."
Therefore, reason is a system of thought that creates insight that allows one to subordinate future thoughts to certain facts that can be controlled by oneself in situations that "may not be ideal," and it cannot be a subject because it depends on the situation. Meaning must be a dynamic concept according to the times in order to reconstruct the context in order to form a correct human thought system.

Another definition of knowledge: an object of belief that is a fact that has been passively questioned and uncontrollable because of the activity of the manifestation of the event of cognition of experience. The statement that there must be evidence should not be recognized as correct because it overlooks the fact that there has been a time when there was an experience that has limitations in explanation.



Is the text a long quote? If so, please reference. If not, please cut it to a question.

See Reason and see Knowledge.

About this question, is the definition of reason is not correct?

Get the question correct and then maybe it can be answered?
